# Can the babel and inputenc packages be used with plain tex?

Tags: babel, plain-tex, input-encodings

More
particularly, can this latex document be converted to plain tex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=british,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\begin{document}
{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
οὔ μοι τὰ Γύγεω τοῦ πολυχρύσου μέλει,}
he said
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes of course it just depends how much latex code you want to include, this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/is-there-any-software-that-converts-latex-file-to-tex-file/91050#91050 shows how you can add 6 lines to any latex file to allow it to be processed by plain tex, but if you do that it's simpler to use latex really.

Comment: The `babel` documentation has a section about support for `plain`.

Comment: `bplain` is a format that allows users to load babel in Plain (it loads babel's hyphenation switching code); `inputenc`, on the other hand, requires more LaTeX kernel code. So the answer is perhaps *no*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using **LuaTeX** (which obsoletes `inputenc`) and don't use anything that is really `babel` specific, then probably the following example will do (it's very minimal, defines only one font shape, the rest can be done similarly):

```
% Font loading package
\input luaotfload.sty
% Computer Modern Unicode (for Greek)
\font\tenrm={name:CMU Serif Roman:+tlig} at 10pt

% Define new language \polutonikogreek and load its hyphenation patterns
\newlanguage\polutonikogreek
\language\polutonikogreek
\input hyph-el-polyton.tex

% Switch to language 0 (English) as default
\language0
\tenrm

{\language\polutonikogreek
οὔ μοι τὰ Γύγεω τοῦ πολυχρύσου μέλει,}
he said

\bye
```