# Pasting a LaTeX snippet into a Plain TeX document

Tags: plain-tex, latex-misc

Suppose person A writes a short bit of TeX code, and sends it to person B for inclusion as part of a larger document.  The snippet written by A doesn't use anything fancy: no cross-references, citations, sectioning, footnotes, etc. etc.  But it has math, of course, and minimal text formatting commands like bold, italics, enumerated lists, maybe tables, etc.

The problem is that A and B use different flavors of TeX.  I believe that A uses Plain TeX and B uses LaTeX, then usually B can just paste A's code in and it will work, since most of the text-formatting commands in Plain TeX (e.g. `{\bf bold}`) are actually TeX primitives and hence also available in LaTeX even if not the "recommended" style.

If A uses LaTeX and B uses Plain TeX there is more of a problem, since for instance `\textbf{bold}` doesn't exist in Plain TeX.  But of course in this case, B can just define a simple version of it herself.  My question is whether I can save B this work?  Where can I find a short, quick and dirty collection of macro definitions that a Plain TeX user can paste at the top of her document that will enable her to paste in *simple* fragments of LaTeX, using no more than basic text formatting commands and (say) list and tabular environments, and have them come out looking at least vaguely reasonable?  Obviously if the LaTeX code uses anything fairly complicated, then there is no answer to this (short of pasting in or reimplementing all of LaTeX), but it seems that for very simple code it should be possible, and maybe someone has done it before.

Comment: For text formatting only, [plnfss](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/plain/plnfss/) should work.

Comment: @erreka The documentation of plnfss is not very helpful, but poking through the files I don't see any definitions of latex-like macros?

Comment: Supported Commands
`\rmfamily \sffamily \ttfamily \mdseries
\bfseries \upshape \itshape \slshape \scshape
\normalfont
\textrm \textsf \texttt \textmd \textbf \textup \textit \textsl \textsc
\rm \sf \tt \md \bf \up \it \sl \sc`
What is missing?:
- size commands: `\large, \huge` etc. Use `\fontsize{20pt}` instead.
- scaling
- math support is poor

Comment: note `\bf` is not a tex primitive (and not defined by default in latex) so even using plain in latex is not always guaranteed.  The other direction is just as hard as you want to make it, `\mathbf` is easy to define, an ams alignment less so.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- since `amsmath` is derived from ams-tex there might be some hope there, but the thought of trying to implement `tabular` in plain tex strikes terror in me.  there *are* some list-like features in ams-tex (`roster`), but no automatic numbering.  i'm not familiar enough with eplain to know whether that holds promise.

Comment: If you ever looked at the definition of lists and tabulars you wouldn't call them simple ; -).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interesting about `\bf`, thanks for the information.  I guess it's just that all the standard LaTeX documentclasses define it then?  I've never seen an example where it doesn't work in LaTeX.

Comment: The problem is that what is “simple” and what is “complicated” is hard to tell… LaTeX macros / packages aren't divided into categories based on the complexity of their implementation; the practice is to treat every LaTeX macro (and often even every package) as a given, and build on it. So for instance the LaTeX list environment may get fancier and fancier / more complicated, and (as long as it works fine) as this is not user-observable, no one cares or knows.

Comment: Of course, by "simple" I did not mean to refer to the LaTeX implementation with all its bells and whistles, but only to the underlying idea of "enumerated list" which could be implemented in a much simpler way.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you just want enumerated lists in plain TeX (for which there exist many options, e.g. eplain, opmac, or roll your own), or you want what the question asks for (exactly matching LaTeX's syntax and output).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR What the question asks for, and what I want, is to exactly match LaTeX's *syntax* (in simple cases --- no need to handle all the optional arguments to `enumerate` for instance), but not necessarily its output: as I said, the output only needs to look "vaguely reasonable" (e.g. in the case of `enumerate` to produce an enumerated list of *some* sort).

Answer (score 2):

You can always just copy the definitions. The file `miniltx.tex` will help a bit (this already allows latex colour and graphics commands in plain, and defines some internal latex tools, but it does not help a lot with tabular. The file below adds tabular, just the basic version not extended versions from `array` package or `tabularx` etc, also I used `\Lbegin` and `\Lend` to avoid clashing with the `\end` primitive as used by `\bye`.

[image]

```
\catcode`\@=11
\input miniltx

\def\@ignorefalse{\global\let\if@ignore\iffalse}
\def\@ignoretrue {\global\let\if@ignore\iftrue}
\@ignorefalse
\let\ignorespacesafterend\@ignoretrue
\let\@typeset@protect\relax
\def\set@display@protect{\let\protect\string}
\def\set@typeset@protect{\let\protect\@typeset@protect}
\def\protected@edef{%
   \let\@@protect\protect
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \afterassignment\restore@protect
   \edef
}
\def\protected@xdef{%
   \let\@@protect\protect
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \afterassignment\restore@protect
   \xdef
}
\def\unrestored@protected@xdef{%
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \xdef
}
\def\restore@protect{\let\protect\@@protect}
\set@typeset@protect

\def\@endparenv{%
  \addpenalty\@endparpenalty\addvspace\@topsepadd\@endpetrue}
\def\@doendpe{\@endpetrue
     \def\par{\@restorepar
              \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
              \everypar{}\par\@endpefalse}\everypar
               {{\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
                \everypar{}\@endpefalse}}
\newif\if@endpe
\@endpefalse

\def\Lbegin#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\def\@currenvir{#1}%
     \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
     \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  \@ignorefalse
  \begingroup\@endpefalse\reserved@a}
\def\Lend#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
\def\@checkend#1{\def\reserved@a{#1}\ifx
      \reserved@a\@currenvir \else\@badend{#1}\fi}
\let\@currenvline\@empty

\def\extracolsep#1{\tabskip #1\relax}
\def\array{\let\@acol\@arrayacol \let\@classz\@arrayclassz
 \let\@classiv\@arrayclassiv
 \let\\\@arraycr\let\@halignto\@empty\@tabarray}
\def\endarray{\crcr\egroup\egroup}
\def\endtabular{\crcr\egroup\egroup $\egroup}
\expandafter \let \csname endtabular*\endcsname = \endtabular
\def\tabular{\let\@halignto\@empty\@tabular}
\@namedef{tabular*}#1{%
 \setlength\dimen@{#1}%
   \edef\@halignto{to\the\dimen@}\@tabular}
\def\@tabular{\leavevmode \hbox \bgroup $\let\@acol\@tabacol
   \let\@classz\@tabclassz
   \let\@classiv\@tabclassiv \let\\\@tabularcr\@tabarray}
\def\@tabarray{\m@th\@ifnextchar[\@array{\@array[c]}}
\def\@array[#1]#2{%
  \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi
  \bgroup
  \setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{%
    \vrule \@height\arraystretch\ht\strutbox
           \@depth\arraystretch \dp\strutbox
           \@width\z@}%
  \@mkpream{#2}%
  \edef\@preamble{%
    \ialign \noexpand\@halignto
      \bgroup \@arstrut \@preamble \tabskip\z@skip \cr}%
  \let\@startpbox\@@startpbox \let\@endpbox\@@endpbox
  \let\tabularnewline\\%
    \let\par\@empty
    \let\@sharp##%
    \set@typeset@protect
    \lineskip\z@skip\baselineskip\z@skip
    \ifhmode \@preamerr\z@ \@@par\fi
    \@preamble}
\def\@arraycr{%
  ${\ifnum0=`}\fi\@ifstar\@xarraycr\@xarraycr}
\def\@xarraycr{\@ifnextchar[\@argarraycr{\ifnum0=`{\fi}${}\cr}}
\def\@argarraycr[#1]{%
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}${}\ifdim #1>\z@ \@xargarraycr{#1}\else
   \@yargarraycr{#1}\fi}
\let\tabularnewline\relax
\def\@tabularcr{%
  {\ifnum0=`}\fi\@ifstar\@xtabularcr\@xtabularcr}
\def\@xtabularcr{\@ifnextchar[\@argtabularcr{\ifnum0=`{\fi}\cr}}
\def\@argtabularcr[#1]{%
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ifdim #1>\z@
      \unskip\@xargarraycr{#1}%
    \else
      \@yargarraycr{#1}%
    \fi}
\def\@xargarraycr#1{\@tempdima #1\advance\@tempdima \dp \@arstrutbox
   \vrule \@height\z@ \@depth\@tempdima \@width\z@ \cr}
\def\@yargarraycr#1{\cr\noalign{\vskip #1}}
\long\def\multicolumn#1#2#3{\multispan{#1}\begingroup
  \@mkpream{#2}%
  \def\@sharp{#3}\set@typeset@protect
  \let\@startpbox\@@startpbox\let\@endpbox\@@endpbox
  \@arstrut \@preamble\hbox{}\endgroup\ignorespaces}
\def\@xexnoop #1\@@{}
\def\@expast#1{\@xexpast #1*0x\@@}
\def\@xexpast#1*#2#3#4\@@{%
  \edef\reserved@a{#1}%
  \@tempcnta#2\relax
  \ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>\z@\do
       {\edef\reserved@a{\reserved@a#3}\advance\@tempcnta \m@ne}%
    \let\reserved@b\@xexpast
  \else
    \let\reserved@b\@xexnoop
  \fi
  \expandafter\reserved@b\reserved@a #4\@@}
\newif\if@firstamp
\def\@addamp{%
  \if@firstamp
    \@firstampfalse
  \else
    \edef\@preamble{\@preamble &}%
  \fi}
\def\@arrayacol{\edef\@preamble{\@preamble \hskip \arraycolsep}}
\def\@tabacol{\edef\@preamble{\@preamble \hskip \tabcolsep}}
\def\@ampacol{\@addamp \@acol}
\def\@acolampacol{\@acol\@addamp\@acol}
\def\@mkpream#1{\@firstamptrue\@lastchclass6
  \let\@preamble\@empty
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \let\@sharp\relax
  \let\@startpbox\relax\let\@endpbox\relax
  \@expast{#1}%
  \expandafter\@tfor \expandafter
    \@nextchar \expandafter:\expandafter=\reserved@a\do
       {\@testpach\@nextchar
    \ifcase \@chclass \@classz \or \@classi \or \@classii \or \@classiii
      \or \@classiv \or\@classv \fi\@lastchclass\@chclass}%
  \ifcase \@lastchclass \@acol
      \or \or \@preamerr \@ne\or \@preamerr \tw@\or \or \@acol \fi}
\def\@arrayclassz{\ifcase \@lastchclass \@acolampacol \or \@ampacol \or
   \or \or \@addamp \or
   \@acolampacol \or \@firstampfalse \@acol \fi
\edef\@preamble{\@preamble
  \ifcase \@chnum
     \hfil$\relax\@sharp$\hfil \or $\relax\@sharp$\hfil
    \or \hfil$\relax\@sharp$\fi}}
\def\@tabclassz{%
  \ifcase\@lastchclass
    \@acolampacol
  \or
    \@ampacol
  \or
  \or
  \or
    \@addamp
  \or
    \@acolampacol
  \or
    \@firstampfalse\@acol
  \fi
  \edef\@preamble{%
    \@preamble{%
      \ifcase\@chnum
        \hfil\ignorespaces\@sharp\unskip\hfil
      \or
        \hskip1sp\ignorespaces\@sharp\unskip\hfil
      \or
        \hfil\hskip1sp\ignorespaces\@sharp\unskip
      \fi}}}
\def\@classi{%
  \ifcase\@lastchclass
    \@acol\@arrayrule
  \or
    \@addtopreamble{\hskip \doublerulesep}\@arrayrule
  \or
  \or
  \or
    \@arrayrule
  \or
    \@acol\@arrayrule
  \or
    \@arrayrule
  \fi}
\def\@classii{%
  \ifcase\@lastchclass
  \or
    \@addtopreamble{\hskip .5\arrayrulewidth}%
  \fi}
\def\@classiii{\ifcase \@lastchclass \@acolampacol \or
   \@addamp\@acol \or
   \or \or \@addamp \or
   \@acolampacol \or \@ampacol \fi}
\def\@tabclassiv{\@addtopreamble\@nextchar}
\def\@arrayclassiv{\@addtopreamble{$\@nextchar$}}
\def\@classv{\@addtopreamble{\@startpbox{\@nextchar}\ignorespaces
\@sharp\@endpbox}}
\def\@addtopreamble#1{\edef\@preamble{\@preamble #1}}
\newcount\@chclass
\newcount\@lastchclass
\newcount\@chnum
\newdimen\arraycolsep
\newdimen\tabcolsep
\newdimen\arrayrulewidth
\newdimen\doublerulesep
\def\arraystretch{1}    % Default value.
\newbox\@arstrutbox
\def\@arstrut{%
  \relax\ifmmode\copy\@arstrutbox\else\unhcopy\@arstrutbox\fi}
\def\@arrayrule{\@addtopreamble{\hskip -.5\arrayrulewidth
   \vrule \@width \arrayrulewidth\hskip -.5\arrayrulewidth}}
\def\@testpach#1{\@chclass \ifnum \@lastchclass=\tw@ 4 \else
    \ifnum \@lastchclass=3 5 \else
     \z@ \if #1c\@chnum \z@ \else
                              \if #1l\@chnum \@ne \else
                              \if #1r\@chnum \tw@ \else
          \@chclass \if #1|\@ne \else
                    \if #1@\tw@ \else
                    \if #1p3 \else \z@ \@preamerr 0\fi
  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi
\fi}
\def\hline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}
\def\@xhline{\ifx\reserved@a\hline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\arrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\def\vline{\vrule \@width \arrayrulewidth}
\def\cline#1{\@cline#1\@nil}
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\def\multispan{\omit\@multispan}
\def\@multispan#1{%
  \@multicnt#1\relax
  \loop\ifnum\@multicnt>\@ne \sp@n\repeat}
\def\sp@n{\span\omit\advance\@multicnt\m@ne}

\def\@startpbox#1{\vtop\bgroup \setlength\hsize{#1}\@arrayparboxrestore}
\def\@endpbox{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\par\egroup\hfil}
\let\@@startpbox=\@startpbox
\let\@@endpbox=\@endpbox


\catcode`\@=12

\tabcolsep 6pt

aaaaaaaaaaa

\Lbegin{tabular}[c]{lll}

aaa&bbb&ccc\\
1&2&3\\
\Lend{tabular}


\bye
```

Comment: Thanks!  What about `enumerate` and `itemize`?

Comment: @MikeShulman you do the same , add an itemize environment then add more and more code copied from latex.ltx until the undefined command errors go away but it's really not a good idea, by then you will have copied (literally)  half the source of latex into a context where it's never been tested and it will sort of work in simple cases and fail in others and just using the same format for shared documents (hopefully a format that is designed for making documents not just a minimal format designed a a book example) makes much more sense.

Comment: @MikeShulman you can input _all_ of latex.ltx into plain tex and then use all of latex commands in plain if you really want to do that, I have a link....   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91050/1090

Comment: Okay.  I had hoped that someone would have solved this problem already, at least for lists.  Of course the latex list environments are doing all sorts of fancy things, but it seems like it should be straightforward to just translate them into some code that does nothing but prefix a bunch of lines by bullets or incremented numbers.

Comment: @MikeShulman it depends how accurate you want to be you can define `\def\begin#1{} \def\end#1{} \def\item{\par$\bullet$}` and it will set a latex list as bulleted paragraphs, but that may or may not be considered close enough to the original depending on what you need it for.

Comment: For my purposes, I would be happy with an answer that could deal with both itemize and enumerate simultaneously in a very bare-bones way like that.

Comment: Good olde LaTeX 2.09 was somewhat built on plain (the kernel was called `lplain.tex`); that code is far simpler and you may copy chunks from it as needed. That's what I did once for itemize and enumerate a while ago.

Comment: @erreka it's not really any harder to copy from laetx.ltx, that's all I did above, and all I did for `miniltx.ltx`  it's just tedious and not really a good idea compared to simply using latex as designed and tested.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: in that case, it is easier to import the bulk of `latex.ltx` into the Plain document, as you have explained [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91050/52679)

Comment: @erreka easier still to use latex.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I interpret the remaining part of the question: you would like to paste something like the following text:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item January
\item February
\item March
\end{enumerate}
```

into a *plain* TeX document, and get something that vaguely looks like an enumerated list.

The following is one way to solve it.

First, look up how enumerated lists are input, in some macro package available in plain TeX (or implement your own). For example, this is how [eplain](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-eplain.html) does it:

```
\input eplain
\numberedlist
\li January
\li February
\li March
\endnumberedlist
\bye
```

[image: eplain numberedlist]

And this is how [opmac](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html) does it:

```
\input opmac
\begitems \style n
* January
* February
* March
\enditems
\bye
```

[image: opmac begitems style n]

Next, do whatever hacking is necessary to turn that LaTeX syntax into the corresponding plain-TeX-with-macros input. For example, using `eplain` (note my macros can probably be improved):

```
\input eplain
\def\begin#1{
    \def\tmpenumerate{enumerate}
    \def\tmpitemize{itemize}
    \def\tmparg{#1}
    \ifx\tmparg\tmpenumerate
        \bgroup\def\item{\li}\numberedlist
        % May want to implement error-checking here
        \def\end##1{\endnumberedlist\egroup}
    \else
      \ifx\tmparg\tmpitemize
        \bgroup\def\item{\li}\unorderedlist
        \def\end##1{\endunorderedlist\egroup}
      \else
        \message{Unsupported environment #1}
      \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{enumerate}
\item January
\item February
\item March
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item April
\item May
\item June
\end{itemize}

\bye
```

Here, we have pasted the LaTeX snippets `\begin{enumerate} … \end{enumerate}` and `\begin{itemize} … \end{itemize}` into a plain TeX document, and got reasonable lists in the output:

[image: eplain plus hack]

Of course you'll need to come up with similar definitions for every environment you use, and you'll need to do more hackery if you want to support more elaborate syntax like the optional arguments of `enumerate` and so on. But you said

> For my purposes, I would be happy with an answer that could deal with both itemize and enumerate simultaneously in a very bare-bones way like that.

and this is certainly very bare-bones. :-)

Comment: Great; this is the sort of thing I wanted!