# Latex is really just a bunch of Tex macros?

Tags: macros

A  question of no practical  importance, just curious:

One reads that Latex is just a collection of Tex macros. Is this literally true?

A more precisely specified version of the same question: Does there theoretically exist a Tex file latex.tex such that if file1.tex is a valid Latex file and file2.tex is the same as file1.tex except that it starts with the line "\input latex" then passing file2.tex to tex.exe produces the same output, eventually, as passing file1.tex to latex.exe?

Comment: Building the LaTeX format does more-or-less exactly that (the file is called `latex.ltx`) ...

Comment: Yep, literally true. But I don't get what you mean in the "specified version".

Comment: Technically, TeX is mostly just a bunch of TeX macros.

Comment: @skillmon : Means: OP turned into a real-world example, such as `\input latex.ltx \documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello World!\end{document}`, processed with `etex.exe`.

Comment: Leslie Lamport (the author of LaTeX) writes in the manual for LaTeX2e: "LaTeX is your typographic designer, and TeX is its typesetter. The LaTeX commands that you type are translated into lower-level TeX typesetting commands."

Comment: I think that David Carlisle already answered this somwhere here in the site.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Don't you mean "*Plain* TeX is mostly just a bunch of TeX macros"?

Comment: @Marijn : OP is interested in the file containing all those definitions.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/is-there-any-software-that-converts-latex-file-to-tex-file

Comment: @AlexG the OP states that the question is 'of no practical importance', therefore he is possibly more interested in the answer to the general question ('is LaTeX a collection of TeX macros?'), which is (to some extent) answered by Leslie Lamport in the quote, being an authoritative source and all.

Comment: @Marijn Maybe. The topic linked in touhami  's comment seems to answer everything.

Comment: To save time, the program was stopped after init.tex and/or latex.ltx were processed and the RAM image was saved as an executable.

Comment: It does have practical implications. For instance, based on the premise that the answer is "yes", effects that cannot be possibly achieved by TeX alone cannot be achieved by LaTeX alone either.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you kindly provide a source detailing how this is achieved?

Comment: @LongHorn - It has to do with UNIX debugging; you can create a binary image of an executing program and examine memory contents at that point.