# \let\newtoks=\relax % this allows plain.tex to be read in twice

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

```
\let\newtoks=\relax % this allows plain.tex to be read in twice
...
\let\+=\relax % in case this file is being read in twice
```

I came across this when I was studying `plain.tex`. I have some questions:

(1) Under what circumstances do we need to read `plain.tex` twice?

(2) The purpose of these `\let` commands, as far as I can see, is to cancel the previous `\outer` definition of `\newtoks` and `\+`, so that they can be used to define other macros (`\newhelp` and `\sett@b`, respectively). Are there any other purposes?

(3) Are there any more such lines in `plain.tex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see similar in this answer

[Is there any software that converts latex file to tex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/is-there-any-software-that-converts-latex-file-to-tex-file/91050#91050)

Note that isn't exactly inputting `plain.tex` twice but it is inputting code *derived from plain tex* into plain, so the same issues arise.

1.
The most likely case of inputting putting plain twice is a file for a custom format that has

```
\input plain
```

so that it can be run from initex/virtex to initialise a format, but might also be input in a document in a normal plain tex command so input to a format already built with plain.

2.
yes

3.
no

Comment: `\outer` is the most useless, annoying, "feature" in the whole TeX language.

Comment: I guess back in the day it was extremely useful because you didn't have to wait for half an hour for TeX to realize that there is a missing `}` somewhere.  Nevertheless, I would have appreciated a `\noouter` primitive which lets you use a control sequence defined `\outer` in a non-`\outer` context.  Or if it would have at least been allowed to use `\outer` control sequences within outer `\outer` control sequences.  This would facilitate the definition of monadic constructs.